# Is the bonus Affiliation gained from low stats supposed to be attached to the low stat?

Tags: whitehack

On p.5 of *Whitehack* 1.7, the rules explain that having a stat lower than six gives the character a bonus affiliation-type *group*.  Groups of this type have to be pinned to a stat.  The rules don't explicitly note that the bonus affiliation need to be pinned to the low stat that grants it, but it sort of feels like it's suggested.

> An attribute can have two groups, but for each attribute with a score of 5 or less, the character gets one extra affiliation group...

The way that wording starts talking about the  limit to the number of groups that can be pinned to the stat makes it sound like maybe(?) the bonus affiliation is supposed to violate that limit -- but it's far from explicit.

Anyone know of an official clarification or have a principled home-ruling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit the author, Christian Mehrstam, up for answers.  He wrote:

> It goes on that stat, but nothing will break if you do it the other way.

So I'm still not certain that the limit is supposed to bump from 2 to 3 for the low stat, but it sounds like it.  And for sure, it's the author's intention that the bonus affiliation should be pinned to the low stat.